# Set Autofilter with linq and Excel

Tags: c#, excel, linq

Next code run well except last XElement where I have to set Autofilter propertie for all columns. I know the number of columns but rows number could be different in every execution.

Exactly, my doubt is with next element:

```
new XElement("AutoFilter", new XAttribute(x + "Range", "R1C1:R1C1"), 
                           new XAttribute("Xmlns", 
                           "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel")
```

My complete code is (my problem is in the last line):

```
XNamespace aw = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office";
XNamespace x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
   new XElement("Workbook",
      new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"),
      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"),
      new XElement("DocumentProperties", new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
         new XElement("Author", ""),
         new XElement("Created", DateTime.Today),
         new XElement("Company", "")
  ),
      new XElement("ExcelWorkBook",
    new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn=schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
    new XElement("WindowHeight", "16795"),
    new XElement("WindowWidth", "8460"),
    new XElement("WindowTopX", "120"),
    new XElement("WindowTopY", "15"),
    new XElement("ProtectStructure", "False"),
    new XElement("ProtectWindows", "False")
  ),
      new XElement("Styles", new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "Default"), new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "Normal"),
            new XElement("Alignment", "", new XAttribute(ss + "Vertical", "Bottom")),
            new XElement("Borders", ""),
            new XElement("Font", ""),
            new XElement("Interior", ""),
            new XElement("NumberFormat", ""),
            new XElement("Protection", "")
         ),
            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "s21"), new XElement("Font", "", new XAttribute(x + "Family", "Swiss"), new XAttribute(ss + "Bold", "1")), new XElement("NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ss + "Format", @"#,##0.00_ ;[Red]\-#,##0.00\ "))),
            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "s83"), new XElement("NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ss + "Format", @"#,##0.00_ ;[Red]\-#,##0.00\ "))),
            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "porcentaje"), new XElement("Font", "", new XAttribute(x + "Family", "Swiss")),  new XElement("NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ss + "Format", "0%"))),
            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "porcentajeb"), new XElement("Font", "", new XAttribute(x + "Family", "Swiss"), new XAttribute(ss + "Bold", "1")), new XElement("NumberFormat", new XAttribute(ss + "Format", "0%"))),
            new XElement("Style", new XAttribute(ss + "ID", "cabecera"), 
        new XElement("Font", "", new XAttribute(x + "Family", "Swiss"), new XAttribute(ss + "Bold", "1"), new XAttribute(ss + "FontName", "Calibri"), new XAttribute(ss + "Size", "11"), new XAttribute(ss + "Color", "#FFFFFF")),
        new XElement("Alignment", new XAttribute(ss + "Horizontal","Center"), new XAttribute(ss + "Vertical", "Bottom")),
        new XElement("Borders",
new XElement("Border", new XAttribute(ss+ "Position" , "Bottom"), new XAttribute(ss+ "LineStyle" , "Continuous"), new XAttribute(ss+ "Weight" , "1")),
new XElement("Border", new XAttribute(ss+ "Position" , "Left"), new XAttribute(ss+ "LineStyle" , "Continuous"), new XAttribute(ss+ "Weight" , "1")),
new XElement("Border", new XAttribute(ss+ "Position" , "Right"), new XAttribute(ss+ "LineStyle" , "Continuous"), new XAttribute(ss+ "Weight" , "1")),
new XElement("Border", new XAttribute(ss+ "Position" , "Top"), new XAttribute(ss+ "LineStyle" , "Continuous"), new XAttribute(ss+ "Weight" , "1"))
     ),
         new XElement("Interior", new XAttribute(ss + "Color","#92D050"),new XAttribute(ss+ "Pattern","Solid"))
        )
  ),
      new XElement("Worksheet",
    new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "SHEET1"),
    new XElement("Table",
          new XElement("Column", new XAttribute(ss + "Width", "140")),
          new XElement("Row",   new XElement("Cell", 
                new XElement("Cell", new XAttribute(ss + "StyleID", "cabecera"), new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "EMPLOYEE")),
        ),
            from item in lista
            select
            new XElement("Row",  new XElement("Cell", new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), item.EMPLOYEE)),
        ),
    new XElement("WorksheetOptions",
          new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
          new XElement("PageSetup", new XElement("Layout", new XAttribute(x + "Orientation", "Landscape")),
new XElement("Header", new XAttribute(x + "Margin", "0.51181102362204722")),
new XElement("Footer", new XAttribute(x + "Margin", "0.51181102362204722")),
new XElement("PageMargins", new XAttribute(x + "Bottom", "0.98425196850393704"), 
            new XAttribute(x + "Left", "0.74803149606299213"), 
            new XAttribute(x + "Right", "0.74803149606299213"), 
            new XAttribute(x + "Top", "0.98425196850393704"))
),
          new XElement("FitToPage",""),
          new XElement("Print", new XElement("FitHeight","100"),
new XElement("ValidPrinterInfo", ""),
new XElement("PaperSizeIndex", "9"),
new XElement("Scale", "77"),
new XElement("HorizontalResolution", "600"),
new XElement("VerticalResolution", "600")
      ),
          new XElement("Selected", ""),
          new XElement("DoNotDisplayZeros", ""),
          new XElement("Panes", new XElement("Pane", new XElement("Number", "3"),
          new XElement("ActiveRow", "5"),
          new XElement("ActiveCol", "1"))),
          new XElement("ProtectObjects", "False"), new XElement("ProtectScenarios", "False")
               ),
    new XElement("AutoFilter", new XAttribute(x + "Range", 
    string.Format("R1C1:R{0}C1", lista.Count())), 
    new XAttribute("Xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"))
)
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you create a row for each item in `lista` you could try something like that:

```
new XElement("AutoFilter", 
    new XAttribute(
        x + "Range", String.Format("R1C1:R{0}C1", lista.Count())), 
        new XAttribute("Xmlns", 
        "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel")
```

I don't know if it works exactly this way, but I think you can see the principle. (Of course you have to adapt the column count.)

Comment: I´ve tryed replacing "R1C1:R1C1" with String.Format("R1C1:R{0}C1", lista.Count())) but filters don't appear...

Comment: Can't test it. There are some errors in your code which prevent building it.

Comment: Could you try again? Before I removed some lines that I thought wouldnt be necessary.

Comment: It's still buggy. There are commas directly before closing brackets e.g. in the 'from..select' statement. A short fix results in a useless XML only.

Comment: This code works for me except the filter .... when I launch the execution excel is opened and formatted correctly except  filter characteristic

Comment: Sorry, can't get it built. I wonder how you can compile it. But anyhow: I would recommend to add the filter manually in your Excel sheet and save it in Excel 2003 XML format. After that try to rebuild the result exactly in your code. By the way: you have to add the header lines to the lista.Count() for your auto filter it you do it this way.